# java - timestamping iBeacons in array list?

Tags: java

I am working on java code for iBeacons, that adds iBeacons to an array list when found, sorts and displays the list by closest proximity and updates an image according to nearest beacon, this I have completed.

The issue that I am having is getting inactive iBeacons removed from my arraylist. As of now, even if IBeacon is shut off, it still remains in the list. My thought was to timestamp each instance of IBeacon as it is added to the arraylist and remove any not found in last 10 secs or so?

I am new to java programming and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have many options. Maybe an OK first one would be to include active state or time threshold in a custom sort? (i.e. sort old ones to the bottom)

Comment: you should first try then ask for help.

Comment: I have been trying but was unable to get it to work so I am asking for help.

Comment: And by "should", that is according to the StackOverflow ethos. In a professional environment, it would make a lot of sense to discuss your options with a more experienced developer before banging your head on the wall. (Just to clarify the very local sense of "should" here.)

Comment: Hopefully your list consists of some custom Object class.  Add a field to it to store a timestamp.  Set the timestamp in the constructor or with an access method.  Create a method to iterate the list and remove anything that is old.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that does sound like exactly what I am trying to do. can you show me a generic example code of this so I can compare it with my failed attempts? thank you so much for answering

Comment: Post your failed attempt.